# how update Rails ruby minor version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

If a Rails 6 Gemfile includes `ruby "~> 3.0"` and the current Ruby version in the project is 3.0.1, how does one upgrade Ruby to the highest current minor release (3.0.2 at this time) without modifying the Gemfile to specify an exact minor release (which would defeat the purpose of the "~> 3.0")?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specifier ~> has a special meaning, best shown by example. ~> 3.0 is identical to >= 3.0 and < 3.1. So all minor patches are included. See https://bundler.io/gemfile.html.

No need to change your Gemfile just install the gems in the newly installed Ruby version.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `bundle update` is the command to install newer versions of gems within the specified version ranges.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

Comment: yes, but how does one upgrade the RUBY version... here's no "bundle update" for ruby itself

Comment: That depends on how you installed Ruby and on which environment. There are many ways to do that. On my development environment I use RVM (Ruby Version Manager) that makes things easy because I can install multiple versions of Ruby on my system. Perhaps you can clarify what your setup is.